# Sql Server Full DataBase Backup

Tags: sql, sql-server

If backup takes 4 hours to complete, how will SQL Server backup the committed transactions that happen during these 4 hours.

Comment: Go and read Books online to find out how a backup works.

Answer (score 0):

From Books Online:

> A full database backup backs up the whole database. This includes part
>   of the transaction log so that the full database can be recovered
>   after a full database backup is restored. Full database backups
>   represent the database at the time the backup finished.

The key is that full database backups include part of the transaction log. So SQL Server backup the committed transactions that happen during these 4 hours by reading the transaction log.